# Get number of results after filtering ng-repeat with ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am implementing a search function in AngularJS and I want there to be a message "No results found" when there are no matches. Since I am filtering only some of the fields and not all of them, I wrote a separate filter function that is applied in `ng-if` to check if the entry matches the search or not. Now I need to count the resulting panels AFTER `ng-repeat` is finished, so I tried using a directive `after-repeat` and assign a value to a `results` variable in my `SearchController` from inside that directive, but it's not doing anything.

HTML:

```
<div ng-if="searchctrl.results<1">No matches.</div>
<uib-accordion close-others="true"> 
    <uib-accordion-group ng-if="searchfilter(lokal)" is-open="isopen" ng-repeat="lokal in lokale | orderBy:'name'" after-repeat>
        [...]
    </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
```

app.js (with controllerAs for my SearchController):

```
var app = angular.module('ZoiglApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute', 'ngTouch', 'leaflet-directive']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    [...]
    .when('/search/:searchterm', {
        controller: 'SearchController',
        controllerAs:'searchctrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/search.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
});
```

afterRepeat.js:

```
app.directive('afterRepeat', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            if(scope.$last) {
                scope.searchctrl.results = angular.element('.panel').length;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

edit: I'm still searching for a solution. I have answered the two suggestions below with my problems with them. It would be really nice if someone could try to find my error

Answer (score 1):

Just filter your list in an other in your controller and use this new one in your view.

```
$scope.filteredLokale = $filter('filter')($scope.lokale, { param: "paramValue" });
```

After that, get count with "length" parameter.

```
    <uib-accordion close-others="true"> 
    <uib-accordion-group is-open="isopen" ng-repeat="lokal in filteredLokale | orderBy:'name'" >
        [...]
    </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
{{ filteredLokale .length }}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the anser and sorry it took so long for me to reply, but I couldn't look into it sooner. I have now made a custom filter and I can use it in my view `ng-repeat="lokal in lokale | searchFilter:st | orderBy:'name'"` (st is my searchterm) and it works, but I can't get it to work from inside the controller, it returns an empty array. I tried `$scope.filteredLokale = $filter('searchFilter')($scope.lokale, {st: $scope.st});` and also `$scope.filteredLokale = $filter('searchFilter')($scope.lokale, $scope.st);`

Answer (score 0):

You should create an angular filter for your `searchFilter` function instead of using `ng-if`. Then you can assign the filtered array to a variable  called `filteredLokale` like this

```
<uib-accordion-group ng-repeat="lokal in lokale | orderBy:'name' | searchFilter as filteredLokale">
</uib-accordion-group>
Length: {{filteredLokale.length}}
```

Comment: I tried this but the alias doesn't work unfortunately. The list is filtered ok, but I cannot use the variables, they are empty/don't exist